# Origin of η and μ as names for monad natural transformations

Tags: category-theory, monads

I swear I once stumbled across a page explaining the origin of η and μ in the context of monads. Or at the very least, an easy way to remember which is which. But I can't find it.

Is there a historic reason why these two Greek letters were chosen?

Comment: Well, $\mu$ is for "$\mu$ultiplication."

Comment: And for $\eta$ this notation seems to come from the unit arrow in an adjunction, so you would have to look for the origin of this notation

Comment: $m$ for multiplication and $e$ for unit are used in the context of monoids. (The use of $m$ for multiplication is quite obvious, and $e$ probably comes from the early years of group theory where the unit was sometimes called "die Einheit" in the german school.) Now natural transformation usually are denoted by greek letters, so it seems fair to use $\mu$ and $\eta$. It is purely speculative as I'm not sure what is the paper that introduced monads in the first place.

Comment: @pece That is starting to sound familiar. Thank you!

Comment: @Pece With that logic, $\epsilon$ would have been just as natural to use to denote the unit than $\eta$.

Comment: @Max If you look at the original papers, that's not so clear : Kan initially denoted unit and counit of an adjunction with $\kappa$ and $\mu$ (!) respectively, while Huber and Kleisli used $\zeta$ and $\eta$ (!) to prove that every adjunction induces a monad (Huber) and every monad induces an adjunction (Kleisli). They also both used $k$ and $p$ for the unit and multiplication of monads.

Comment: It looks like the first use of $\eta$ and $\mu$ is from Eilenberg and Moore, when they introduced the algebras of monads, but they denoted the units and counits of adjunctions by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (and they used $F$ for the endofunctor of the monad). Jon Beck, in his thesis and his paper on (co)homology with Barr, used the $(T,\eta,\mu)$ notation for monads, $(G,\epsilon,\delta)$ for a comonad, and $\eta$ and $\epsilon$ for the unit and counit of adjunctions.